# How to force Visual Studio not to add GlobalSection(Performance) section?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, profiling, projects-and-solutions

I played with Visual Studio builtin profiling tools and now every time I check out any file this section automatically adds to my solution file:

```
GlobalSection(Performance) = preSolution
    HasPerformanceSessions = true
EndGlobalSection
```

I totally removed all profiling reports, then removed local copy of all source control files from this solution and update to latest. This section still in *.sln file after any checkout.

Other teammates who haven't used prfiler doesn't have this problem.
Has anyone any ideas?

Comment: which version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: Visual Studio 12. Yes your answer is right I read about it but... it doesn't work for me... maybe I did smt wrong

Comment: Are you sure that the Solution file in your source control does not have the GlobalSection entry? Have you checked the file in the Source Control Explorer?

Comment: Related: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/817315/section-in-solution-file-causes-continual-merge-conflicts-in-a-team-environment

Comment: Actually, it might be helpful if everyone that can reproduce this issue say so on the [connect issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/817315/section-in-solution-file-causes-continual-merge-conflicts-in-a-team-environment) (there's link next to "Repros" when you're signed in, and/or you could leave a comment).  That way, it might get fixed some day - this really looks like a trivial bug.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Open the PerformanceExplorer in Visual Studio by using the Menu `Analyze -> Windows -> PerformanceExplorer` and check if it lists any session entries.

If so delete them by doing a right-click on an entry to open the ContextMenu. Then select "Remove" from the menu.

You should also check the folder of your solution if it contains any `.vsp` or `.psess` files and delete them. These are the report files of a profiling session.

Comment: As if solution files aren't hard enough to merge as they are...The IDE altering the .sln with this means that in most teams of more than 1, if just 1 person has run a profiler (or only 1 hasn't etc), the sln will have a merge conflict every single time...grrrrr

Comment: In my case Performance Explorer is empty and no `*.vsp` and `*.psess` files are present, but VS still adds these lines to the solution file. Any ideas?

Comment: Connect issue: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/817315/section-in-solution-file-causes-continual-merge-conflicts-in-a-team-environment

Comment: In VS 2015, with General settings applied, the "Show Performance Explorer" menu item is under "Debug >> Profiler >> Performance Explorer"

Answer (score 4):

Only way I could solve this was to close the solution, delete *.psess and *.vsp files from the root directory, reset my .sln file to the remote version and reopen the solution. Problem was then gone. This was using Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition.